# Value Error: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) with string splitting of a text file line(relevant code below)

Tags: python, tensorflow, spyder

The code was supposed to create a live graph of two pieces of tensor flow data, but instead just created a 1 by 1 graph with no data inside of it.

This is a function to turn the text file into a list of Xs and Ys.

```
def animate(i):
    graph_data = open('NeuralNetData.txt','r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x, y = line.split(',')
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)

style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

f= open("NeuralNetData.txt","a+")
```

computational graph of neural network

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
print("Initialized")
for step in range(num_steps):
    # Pick an offset within the training data, which has been randomized.
    # Note: we could use better randomization across epochs.
    offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
    # Generate a minibatch.
    batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    # Prepare a dictionary telling the session where to feed the minibatch.
    # The key of the dictionary is the placeholder node of the graph to be fed,
    # and the value is the numpy array to feed to it.
    feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
    _, l, predictions = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
    if (step % 500 == 0):
        f= open("NeuralNetData.txt","a")
        print("Minibatch loss at step {}: {}".format(step, l))
        print("Minibatch accuracy: {:.1f}".format(accuracy(predictions, batch_labels)))
        print("Validation accuracy: {:.1f}".format(accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels)))
```

where the problem starts

```
        x=str(step)
        y=str(accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))
        f.write(x+y)
        f.close()
        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post the full error traceback in your question.

Comment: instead of `x, y = line.split(',')` try `temp = line.split(',')` then `if len(temp) != 2: print("{} does not have 2 elements!".format(line)) else: x = temp[0]; y = temp[1]`. I'm sure you'll get more insight if you can see the line of your file giving you problems

Comment: `x, y = line.split(',')` If line doesn't contain a comma, `split()` will return a sequence with only one value, but you're trying to pull two values out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on the error in the title, the value of your 'line' doesn't seem split-able into two parameters on your `x, y = line.split(',')` line. You can add an additional check as:

```
if line and "," in line:
    x, y = line.split(',')
```

Or better yet, split and then see if you got two values:

```
if line:
    pos = line.split(",")
    if len(pos) > 1:
        xs.append(pos[0])
        ys.append(pos[1])
```